# Postgres Time inaccuracy

Tags: postgresql

I have not used Postgresql that much however, I have ran into a bit of an issue.

I am running a query on some dates, all was going well until I actually analyzed them. For one row example, I get returned this...

2014-07-04 01:05:18

Which at first I thought was fine, but then I looked on the Website that is using this data, and the Website is displaying the data as...

2014-07-04 11:05:18

I can't really go at looking through the websites code, because it is some 3rd party website which has massive amounts of logic which I practically can't understand without devoting time. I asked on here because I don't really know how to ask the question on google.

The query is:

```
SELECT T.objectid AS "Ticket Number", 
        created AS "Time Responded", 
        (SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = T.creator) AS "Name"
FROM transactions AS T 
WHERE created > '2014/07/01 23:59:59' 
  AND created < '2014/07/06 00:00:00' 
  AND creator = (
         SELECT memberid 
         FROM groupmembers AS G 
         WHERE G.memberid = T.creator
         AND G.groupid = '42')
  AND type = 'Correspond';
```

Cheers

Comment: Most likely a timezone problem. Can hopefully be compensated by adjusting how it is displayed.

Comment: Please show us your query you use to display the data (also which SQL client are you using). What data type is that column?

Comment: Hello, SELECT T.objectid AS "Ticket Number", created AS "Time Responded", (SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = T.creator) AS "Name"
FROM transactions AS T
WHERE created > '2014/07/01 23:59:59' AND created < '2014/07/06 00:00:00'
AND creator = (SELECT memberid FROM groupmembers AS G where G.memberid = T.creator and G.groupid = '42')
AND type = 'Correspond';

Comment: No code in comments, please, edit your question instead and put the code there, well formatted and indented.

Comment: Please show the output of `SHOW TimeZone` too.